# How to read multiple raster files and get average value for each one?

Tags: r, raster

I have 25 tif rasters. I need an overall mean value for each raster. Is there anyway I can stack or read in all 25 tifs simultaneously and output 25 seperate average values?

Comment: they share the same extent?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sapply` to read in all the raster files and calculate their mean values all in one operation. Here's an example using three random `tiff` files that you can adapt to your needs. The code below assumes the tiff files are in your current working directory.

```
# Get the names of the tiff files in the current working directory
rastFiles = list.files(pattern="tif")

rastFiles
[1] "density.tiff"   "NE1_50M_SR.tif" "ortex.tiff"  

# Read in all the tiff files in rastFiles, calculate their means and 
# return the means in a vector
rastMeans = sapply(rastFiles, function(filename) {
  r = raster(filename)
  return(mean(values(r), na.rm=TRUE))
})

rastMeans

density.tiff NE1_50M_SR.tif     ortex.tiff 
    188.5550       238.7883       214.6870
```

Comment: This is not memory-safe. Instead of mean(values(r), na.rm=T), you should use cellStats(r, 'mean', na.rm=TRUE)

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "not memory-safe". Also, when I tried using `cellStats`, I got an integer overflow for one of my sample TIFF files, but there doesn't seem to be a way, within `cellStats`, to convert the values to numeric before running `mean`. Do you know of a solution for that?

Comment: memory safe means that the function, when files are large, won't attempt to load all values into RAM; but rather process the files in chunks. Interesting error. I suppose multiplying by 1 would fix it.